# hot to put a delimiter into output of "lsusb"

Tags: php, linux, bash, sed, lsusb

I have an "lsusb" output as below:

```
khalemi@hpx:/opt$ lsusb -d 0c2e:0200
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
```

Q) How can I use "sed" to reformat the output ( using delimiter ---) to be like

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
---
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
```

I will then pass this output to another process like php script, and explode/split it using (---) delimiter into array.

please help.

Comment: Why bother with this when you could just split in PHP on `\n` (newline)?

Comment: i tried that i doesn't work. but later I found out that i had to put "\n" instead of '\n' in explode() for it to work as expected. my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, you could do like

Through `preg_split`

```
$str = <<<EOT
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
EOT;
$split = preg_split('~\n~', $str);
print_r($split);
```

With `explode`,

```
$split = explode("\n", $str);
```

This splits the input according to the newline character.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
    [1] => Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
)
```

Comment: Well done, solving the actual problem and removing the hacks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
lsusb -d 0c2e:0200 | awk 'NR>1{print "---\n" $0}'
```

Using `sed`:

```
lsusb -d 0c2e:0200 | sed '1!s/^/---\n/'
```

In both cases, the code works by adding `---\n` before every line except for the first line.

Answer (score 0):

another approach

**using sed**

```
lsusb -d 0c2e:0200|sed '$!{s/$/&\n---/g}'
```

**results**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
---
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0c2e:0200 Metrologic Instruments Metrologic Scanner
```